Protégé 5.6.4 fails to start after WinGet installation with "Cannot find Java class" error despite multiple JDK versions available
I installed Protégé 5.6.4 using WinGet:
winget install Protégé

which completed successfully:
Found Protégé [Stanford.Protege] Version 5.6.4
This application is licensed to you by its owner.
Microsoft is not responsible for, nor does it grant any licenses to, third-party packages.
Downloading https://github.com/protegeproject/protege-distribution/releases/download/protege-5.6.4/Protege-5.6.4-win.zip
Successfully verified installer hash
Extracting archive...
Successfully extracted archive
Starting package install...
Command line alias added: "protege"
Path environment variable modified; restart your shell to use the new value.
Successfully installed

However, when I run protege.exe from %LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\WinGet\Links\, I get:
CompileCommand: exclude javax/swing/text/GlyphView.getBreakSpot bool exclude = true
protege: Cannot start Java: Cannot find Java class

I have multiple Java versions installed:
> where java
C:\Program Files\Eclipse Adoptium\jre-21.0.5.11-hotspot\bin\java.exe
C:\Program Files\Eclipse Adoptium\jre-8.0.432.6-hotspot\bin\java.exe
C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\java8path\java.exe
C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath\java.exe
C:\Program Files\AdoptOpenJDK\jdk-15.0.2.7-hotspot\bin\java.exe
C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath\java.exe
C:\Program Files\Microsoft\jdk-11.0.16.101-hotspot\bin\java.exe
C:\Program Files\OpenJDK\jdk-22.0.2\bin\java.exe

I've tried setting both Java 11 and Java 8 as default via JAVA_HOME and PATH, but the error persists. Running it directly with Java also fails:
"C:\Program Files\Microsoft\jdk-11.0.16.101-hotspot\bin\java.exe" -jar "%LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\WinGet\Links\protege.exe"


Error: Invalid or corrupt jarfile %LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\WinGet\Links\protege.exe

How can I get Protégé to start properly?

The WinGet installation of Protégé actually creates a full installation in the packages directory. Instead of using the protege.exe shortcut, you can run Protégé directly using its batch file:
"%LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\WinGet\Packages\Stanford.Protege_Microsoft.Winget.Source_8wekyb3d8bbwe\Protege-5.6.4\run.bat"

This launches Protégé correctly, using the appropriate Java configuration from the batch file rather than relying on system-wide Java settings.
You can create a shortcut to this batch file for easier access if needed.
mklink "path\to\Desktop\Protégé.lnk" "path\to\Protege-5.6.4\run.bat"

